# Repopulating textarea with EXACTLY what the user submitted (with ASCII codes and without additonal forward slashes before some characters)

Tags: php, forms

I have a textarea, which I need to be able to take characters including / and ' as well as special characters in ASCII. It does this fine, and sends the data to a php page by the POST method.

Then I repopulate the text area simply by putting

```
<?php echo isset($F_Text) ? $F_Text : '' ?>
```

between the textarea tags ($F_Name = $_POST["F_Name"]), with the intention that the user can then alter what they typed in and resubmit.

But each time the form is repopulated two issues arise. A forward slash is added before characters such as ' and the ASCII characters are printed out as the symbol rather than the code. This basically breaks the rest of the page (the submission goes on to be processed by some javascript).

I can't think of any way to keep the ASCII codes as just that, codes, not symbols.

Also, I've just noticed that all $ signs are lost too, which I can understand, but I need them to stay!

I need the form to display EXACTLY what the user typed in originally. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with :

```
<?php echo isset($F_Text) ? htmlentities(stripslashes($F_Text)) : '' ?>
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: That does solve part of my problem (thanks), namely the added slashes. I've noticed now that all $ signs are being lost and I need those to stay.

Comment: Can you please post what is the repopulated value you are getting when posting $ or any other ASCI code

Comment: Okay, so the form takes jqmath (http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html). If, for example, "$$t'=&#947;(t-{vx}/c^2)$$$$x'=&#947;(x-vt)$$$$y'=y$$$$z'=z$$" is entered, "t'=&#947;(t-{vx}/c^2)x'=&#947;(x-vt)y'=yz'=z" is repopulated. I'm thinking about replacing $ signs with something else when the form is submitted, then replacing them back again when repopulating the form. ASCI codes seem otherwise fine now.

Comment: Note that the $ signs are originally still there when it's echoed, just not in the form.

Comment: I see here the $ signs are completely missing. I tried in a form I created worked perfectly fine it repopulated with the entered code. I think some thing will be there while you are processing data. What are you replacing $ sign with

Comment: Nothing yet, I was just going to try that. I'm literally just POSTing them then using your bit of code above to repopulate a <textarea>. It works fine with a <input> so I guess I could just use one of them instead.

Comment: Hmmm. Was working for me with text area and input box. Can't get what the issue is :( sorry

Comment: I find it to be very strange behaviour, but I'm happy with an input box so I'll just use one of them and be done with it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you first have to turn of [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php), then use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to avoid that your variable messes up your html and then make sure everything is in utf8 so that all special characters are retained (depending on what you consider ASCII characters...).

Your php echo statement would be:

```
<?php echo isset($F_Text) ? htmlspecialchars($F_Text) : '' ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The ASCII characters I'm refering are mostly greek letters, but as per Sabari's answer are no longer an issue. The only prevailing issue is that $ signs are lost.